# Parsing several files (one by one) with rapidXML to use less memory

Tags: memory-management, xml-parsing, rapidxml

I need to read a big XML file (~5.4 GB). I noted that parsing the file with rapidXML uses about 6 times more RAM than the size of the file on disk (so parsing a 200 MB file requires ~1.2 GB of RAM and the 5.4 GB file would require ~32.4 GB of RAM !). To avoid swapping, I decided to split the file in smaller chunks and read those chunks one by one (using the 'xml-split' tool from the [comma](https://github.com/acfr/comma/wiki/XML-Utilities) library). I can read and parse the XML files correctly.

**The problem :** When I reach the end of the first file I can successfully open the second one, but the first file still uses memory, even if I clear the `rapidxml::document` and/or delete the `rapidxml::file<>`. Here is the header file :

```
//*1st code snippet*
//.h file
#include "rapidxml_utils.hpp"        //Implicitly includes 'rapidxml.hpp'
...
private:
  std::basic_ifstream<char> inStream;
  rapidxml::file<>* sumoXmlFile;
  rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
  uint16_t fcdFileIndex;               //initialized at 0
...
```

Here is the code to open a new XML file :

```
//*2nd code snippet*
//.cc file
bool parseNextFile()
{
  //check if file exists (filenames are : fcd0.xml, fcd1.xml, fcd2.xml, etc.)
  struct stat buffer;
  std::string fileName = std::string("fcd") + std::to_string(fcdFileIndex) + ".xml";
  bool fileExists = (stat(fileName.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);

  if(!fileExists)
    return false;

  //"increment" the name for the next file (when this method will be recalled)
  fcdFileIndex++;

  //open a reading stream, create the 'file' and parse it
  inStream.open(fileName.c_str(), std::basic_ifstream<char>::in);
  sumoXmlFile = new rapidxml::file<>(inStream);
  doc.parse<0>(sumoXmlFile->data());

  return true;
}
```

I call `parseNextFile()` in the code a first time (to open the 1st file). Then, the `update()` method is called regularly:

```
//*3rd code snippet*
void update()
{
  //Read next tag
  rapidxml::xml_node<>* node = doc.first_node("timestep");

  //If no 'timestep' tags are left, clean and parse the next file.
  if(!node)
  {
    doc.clear();         //**not sure**
    delete sumoXmlFile;  //**not sure**
    inStream.close();    //**not sure**

    if(parseNextFile())  //See 2nd code snippet
      node = doc.first_node("timestep");
    else
      return;
  }

  //read the children nodes of the current 'timestep'
  for(rapidxml::xml_node<>* veh = node->first_node(); veh; veh = node->first_node())
  {
    ...
    //read some attributes using 'veh->first_attribute("...")'
    ...

    node->remove_first_node();
  }

  doc.remove_first_node();
}
```

The issue is (I think) when 'cleaning' (the lines labeled as 'not sure' in the previous code snippet). I tried several combinations of `clear()`, `delete`, calling the `memory_pool` destructor. Nothing I tried frees memory. I also directly opened the XML files with

```
sumoXmlFile = new rapidxml::file<>(fileName.c_str()); //see 2nd code snippet
```

instead of creating the `ifstream` manually.

**To summarize**, when I open the first XML file, it loads successfully and some RAM is used. When I'm done with it, I try to clean/delete/clear the memory pool (without success) and open the second file (with success). At this point, the 1st and 2nd files use memory. Parsing the 2nd file works correctly (even the 3rd, 4th, and so on), but the RAM gets pretty full at some point.

(Finally) **My question :** Did I do something wrong in releasing the memory used by the first file ? Is it possible to release the memory used then read the next file ? I do not mind destroying the XML files in the process if it is required.

(For the sake of completeness : this code is actually an [OMNeT++](https://omnetpp.org/) simulation and the XML file is generated by [SUMO](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/index.html). I am sure the XML file is error-free.)

Thanks for any help or hints that can be provided !

Comment: I don't see anything much wrong with that. Personally I'd wrap the xmldoc, file and ifstream in a single object that's deleted and constructed afresh for each file, rather than trying to clear and reuse those, but I don't expect that to fix your problem. How are you measuring the memory use?

Comment: Hmm... I can try to wrap everything in an object, see what it does. I use the system monitor (more precisely KDE's KSysGuard). I pause the simulation just before the next XML file is to be read (I cut the files each 1000 seconds, so I know when it is) and continue the simulation step-by-step :  I see the RAM usage jumping from ~1.2 GB to ~3.0 GB.

Comment: UPDATE: Wrapping the parser in a dedicated object does not help : the memory is not freed after a call to the destructor :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by extracting the useful information from the XML file with a Python [script](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). The script then creates a [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) file that is read line-by-line in OMNeT (C++) using a `std::istream`.